# Extension connects to Google API

Tags: google-sheets, firefox, google-cloud-platform, firefox-addon

I wonder if there has been any tutorial on how an extension can communicate to Google API because I couldn't find any. I attempted to do so, but there was not any error or recommendation for me to correct or learn.

Comment: What do you mean by `but it only loaded apis.google.com`?

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou The network tab shows only apis.google.com is requested, which is way fewer than when I run the tutorial